# Receiving a status 429 too many requests when executing code in cloud function but not when executing it locally

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions

I want to automate an api call with cloud functions but it does not work.
The code works fine locally but I receive 429 when using cloud functions.
Is there a way to handle it in code? or is it a problem with my account?
This is the api call:

```
def get_visits(request):
endpoint = "https://api.mercadolibre.com/items/visits?ids=" + str(i) + "&date_from=" + str(yesterday) + "T00:00:00.000-00:00&date_to=" + str(today) + "T00:00:00.000-00:00"
payload={}
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token}
response = requests.get(endpoint, headers=headers, data=payload)
if response.status_code != 200:    
    print('API response: ', response.text)
else:
    return response.json()
```

Comment: 429 is comming from you `api.mercadolibre.com` call ... it has nothing to do with where you are calling it from most likely (but maybe you need to register ip addresses with the api.mercadolibre) ... but most likely you are just exceeding your rate limits

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'll investigate how to register ip address. The thing is the same api call I. do it with two different brands. One works fine and not the other that requires more calls

Comment: that sounds like you are calling to fast with "requires more calls" ... add a few second sleep between calls (I dont know what their rate limits are)

Comment: when I added a time.sleep(10) the cloud functions fails with a health check to false error

Comment: cloud functions also have timeouts ... so you have to complete everything in that window or your cloudfunction will be marked unhealthy

Comment: The cloud function timeout is set to the max. There are 1300 calls with a time.sleep(2) ending in the following log message: Ready condition status changed to False.Revision  is not ready and cannot serve traffic. The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable.

Comment: The reason for this response code is probably that you have exceeded the quota limit for number of API calls per minute/hour etc.  In this case, there may actually not be a response or body in the result, but the http status code is received with no content.

Answer (score 0):

We implemented a rate limit restriction in order to control the requests sended to the API. The rate limit is configured to 1500 requests per minute per seller, if you exceed this limit, you will receive an empty response with a 429 status code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Perhaps you could expand on how to accomplish this.